# Visual representation of (right or left) ideals of a ring?

Tags: ideals

I would like to know about the canonical visual representation for ideals in a ring. Particularly, for the two kinds of one-sided ideals,that is, right ideals and left ideals. Is it possible to use Venn diagrams or the like in order to represent them? Some examples of visual representations would be very welcome.

Comment: I am not certain if there is such a thing. I am fairly certain there is no canonical one.

Comment: Ok, a humble formulation would be: how is it possible to visually represent one-sided ideals of a ring? Venn Diagrams? Graphs? Lattices?

Comment: Maybe this is of some interest for you all: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610613/on-publication-regarding-right-ideals-of-a-ring-and-the-sublanguages-of-science?noredirect=1#comment3282962_1610613